# No sound after suspend 16.04

Tags: sound, suspend, pulseaudio

I'm running Ubuntu 16.04 on my Toshiba S55dt-A5130

I had no sound after a fresh install.
I figured out that I had to re-install Ubuntu with security settings in BIOS on CSM in stead of UEFI. That solved the problem.

So my sound works after a fresh boot, but after suspend it doesn't work anymore.

The weird thing is that in Pulseaudio I do see audio pulses if I test the sound.

Comment: Whats the output of `lscpi | grep Audio`

Comment: 00:01.1 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Trinity 
    HDMI Audio Controller
    00:14.2 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH Azalia 
    Controller (rev 01)